# Product rule for square roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

For real numbers, $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$ only if at least one of $a$ or $b$ is greater than $0$.

What does the corresponding rule look like for complex numbers? I understand that complex numbers aren't really comparable to each other (or $0$).
For $a = 2+3i$ and $b=3+2i$, $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$ is true.
However, it clearly doesn't work for $a = -2-3i$ and $b=-3-2i$

Comment: For non-negative real numbers $x$, $\sqrt x$ usually denotes the non-negative square root, but such square roots aren’t uniquely defined for complex numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does that mean a statement like $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$ incorrect/incomplete? $\sqrt{-4}$ could have been $-2i$ as well, as there isn't a well defined way to compare $2i$ or $-2i$ to 0.

Comment: I agree with that

Comment: Yeah.  $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$ is really one of those irritatingly incorrect statements.  $\sqrt{}$ is not really a very usefull or meaningful symbols.  ... But this rule is always true.  If $\alpha^2 = a$ and $\beta^2 = b$ then $(\alpha\beta)^2 = ab$. Could be the general rule. Or $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \pm \sqrt{a}\sqrt b$ if we have a way of designating what we mean by "the" square root.

Comment: When discussing complex numbers, [some authors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) use the $\sqrt{\quad}$ symbol to denote the principal square root. This usage is fine (and handy) if the convention is made explicit. (Then it must be noted that *if the bases aren't real positive numbers*, the usual exponential laws may not hold.)$\quad$Going off on a tangent: when $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $w,z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},$ it is true that $(wz)^n = w^n z^n.$